# How do I create a simple search box with a submit button to bring back a result set in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC and just learning the basics.  I have been following along in Nerd Dinner and used the demo as a way to create my own app.  I have created a page that lists out some food items with calories, fat, protein,etc...  (http://rjsfitness.net/CalorieList)  This is one of my own personal sites that I set up to test out MVC.  I got a lot of it working but I am stuck on the textbox with a search button.

My view page has this code for the search:

```
    <form action="/CalorieList/Search" method="post" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="searchTerm" id="searchTerm" value="" size="10" maxlength ="30" />
  <input type ="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

My global.asax has this code for the routing:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Search", // Route name
            "CalorieList/Search/{searchTerm}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "CalorieList", action = "Search", search = "" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

My Controller has this code:

```
        public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        const int pageSize = 10;

        //load a list with the calorie list
        var calorieLists = calorieListRepository.GetAllCalorieLists();

        //var paginatedCalorieLists = calorieLists.Skip((page ?? 0) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        var paginatedCalorieLists = new PaginatedList<CalorieList>(calorieLists, page ?? 0, pageSize);

        return View("Index", paginatedCalorieLists);
    }

    public ActionResult Search(String searchTerm)
    {
        const int pageSize = 100;
        int? page = 0;

        var calorieLists = calorieListRepository.GetCalorieListsBySearch(searchTerm);

        var paginatedCalorieLists = new PaginatedList<CalorieList>(calorieLists, page ?? 0, pageSize);

        return View("Index", paginatedCalorieLists);
    }

        return View("Index", paginatedCalorieLists);
    }
```

When I enter a value and click the button, the Index method fires instead of the Seach method in the controller and I get the full list again.  If I manually type the url (http://rjsfitness.net/CalorieList/Search/choc) I get the right listing.

Why isn't my button click using the right routing and giving me the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is actually pointing to this:

```
<form id="form1" action="CalorieList" method="post">
```

If you are using Html.BeginForm, you are passing in the wrong parameters.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "CalorieList")) %>
<% { %>
// Your form fields
<% } %>
```

On a side note, why is there ViewState on your page?

Comment: so should I point the action to CalorieList/Search to get it to work.  And I have no idea why there is ViewState on the page but good catch.  I'll have to try to figure that one out.

Comment: The wierd thing is that on the View page the actual code is, <form action="/CalorieList/Search" method="post" id="searchForm"> but the View source shows <form method="post" action="calorielist" id="form1">
 with the viewstate as well as the code above.  I have no idea  where the viewstate is coming from.

Comment: Is it actually a webform that you are pointing to a controller action?

Comment: Found the ViewState problem.  I had a runat=server on the main form.  I also found the problem with the search.  The search form was inside the main form.  I moved it out and it worked but I like your solution better.  I put your using code on the page and the resulting html is identical to the form code I had.  But it looks cleaner your way.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Because I think you're going back to the Index ActionResult.  Put a breakpoint in your Index action and see.

You might want to Return to a route rather than a View.

**EDIT**

Or have a Search view to return to.

Or you could do a jQuery post back and return a PartialView and replace the content of a div with the returned partial view html.

If this is what you want post a comment and i can provide code and links.

**EDIT 2**

I explain it a bit in this question.  Please add another comment if you need further code or samples and I'll post no problem.

[another approach to returning some thing to browser in mvc with ajax call instead of using response.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845253/another-approach-to-returning-some-thing-to-browser-in-mvc-with-ajax-call-instead/2853547#2853547)

Comment: Yes, I am definitely going back to the Index.  I did put a breakpoint in and it is doing just that.  I think I explained that above but it probably got lost in all the text. 

Yes, what you explained is exactly what I want and I have seen some examples of the different methods you explained but I just am so new to this a few code examples would be great.

Thanks for the help.